# Images and fonts not found (404) on a local web page

Tags: css

This is driving me nuts.  This is should be simple - but I can't tell what I am doing wrong.

I have a plain old web site. Index.html, a css folder, images folder, fonts folder and js folder.

I am trying to add a font through the @font-face declaration.

[image]

I run the page locally and I get 404s for both the font file and the background image?

The paths are correct?

[image]

Comment: This probably won't be the fix, but just to try the obvious tell it to explicitly go back through the folder structure by adding two dots (..) in front of your folder names (ie; '../images/chicago.jpg')

Comment: Yeah that was it.  Strange.  I thought web storm would have taken care of that.

Comment: Probably isn't checking the logic of the "why," it just sees that it is valid, which technically it is. When in doubt, try the obvious even when you think it's being accounted for by your system.

Comment: Looks like you are using gulp. Are you using it to load your css and fonts?

Answer (score 0):

You are pointing to the wrong directory.
Try to add /../ before your path. Like:

```
src: url(/../fonts/in901xk.ttf)
```

This give an "step back" to the main directory and now can point to the "fonts" folder.

Other option to check this, for example in the case of images, is write the complete url that you think is the correct.If you can see the image, you will know what is the correct path that you should use in your src